MFC CEdit and CCombobox - Want Ctrl+ Backspace to Delete Whole Word instead of outputting "Square" 127 Character
Traditionally, pressing Ctrl+ Backspace in a Win32 text control such as an Edit or ComboBox would generate a delete control character corresponding to ASCII code 127. In many Windows applications such as the Windows 10 version (and before) of Notepad, ctrl+ backspace will generate a "square" character. See below: 
MFC and earlier versions of .Net wrapped Win32 WinForm Controls exhibited this "square" character behavior when ctrl+ backspace was pressed. However, in newer versions of .Net the out of the box behavior was changed so for each ctrl+ backspace the most recent whole word in the control would be deleted. This conforms with many other text controls such as those found on webpages. With regard to .Net controls, the earliest versions, the controls worked just like their MFC counterparts with regard to this behavior. Then with the arrival of "autocomplete", the behavior was avaiable but not by default (see this link Winforms Textbox - Using Ctrl-Backspace to Delete Whole Word). With VS 2019, the behavior is available from the get-go.
Does anyone have a simple MFC solution to change the "out of the box" behavior of controls such as and CComboBox to delete the most recent whole word instead of outputting the character 127 "square"? I've seen some projects online that implement an entire autocomplete interface but that is overkill for the one change I require. Worse case, I figure I could subclass the controls and in the wnd message loop, delete the last word whenever a character 127 is encountered.
I would like to hear your suggestions :-)

This is not a behaviour the edit control has. The only way to retrofit it is to subclass the control, catch the keypress, and do the manipulation of the contents yourself.

Yes, that is what I suspected. It seems that the MFC controls did not get the same upgrades that their .Net wrapped counterparts had.

The edit-box (Window class "Edit" or WC_EDIT) are not "MFC" controls (ie there's no subclassing by the MFC library), they are instead Win32 controls, and the MFC class CEdit is a thin wrapper. A (non-MFC) Win32 application behaves the same. Notepad (which uses a multiline edit control for editing the text) works well though!...

I didn't know that these features even existed, but this provoked my curiosity. Searched the internet and found similar questions and reports, and found that this indeed relates to the Windows Autocomplete Functionality.
For the testing, I created a non-MFC Win32 application, displaying a dialog-box containing a standard Win32 Edit-Control. Pressing Ctrl + Backspace inserted char 127 rather than deleted the last word, ie it showed the "old" behavior by default.
This can be changed by enabling Autocomplete for the edit control. Add the following lines in your source:
// Your MFC project may already be including these
#include <objbase.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

In your InitInstance() function (CWinApp::InitInstance() in MFC) add:
    CoInitialize(NULL); // The documentation suggests using CoInitializeEx() instead

In your dialog procedure add the following line in the WM_INITDIALOG message processing block add:
    SHAutoComplete(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1), SHACF_AUTOAPPEND_FORCE_OFF | SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_OFF);

In MFC's OnInitDialog() this would become:
    SHAutoComplete(::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd IDC_EDIT1), SHACF_AUTOAPPEND_FORCE_OFF | SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_OFF);

I chose the SHACF_AUTOAPPEND_FORCE_OFF and SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_OFF flags so as to disable as many Autocomplete operations as possible. This causes the edit-box to work as desired, as it appears to subclass the control. Checked the control with the Spy++ utility and found that after the call it has the same window-procedure as the edit-control in Notepad, which wasn't the case before!
A downside is that every single edit-control (for which you want the feature enabled) must be subclassed - couldn't find a way to enable it for the whole dialog, or the whole application. If you are going to use many such controls, it may make sense to define a new C++ (and subclass the controls using the Class-Wizard),
Note: You will have to add Shlwapi.lib to your project libraries, if you are getting an unresolved external error for SHAutoComplete().
Now, if it is worth to add this to your project or instead process keyboard input yourself, is a matter of choice only, as the work required is not very much in either case. A criterion can be not having to mess with the autocomplete features.
